# Asp.Net Core HTTPContext and RewritePath

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am converting over an old `HttpModule` into a new `MiddleWare` and want to know what is the correct way for Rewriting the Path in the `MiddleWare`.

The old module uses this:

```
context.RewritePath(path, string.Empty, queryPart);
```

Answer (score 0):

For simple rules, you should be able to just alter the `request.Path` [, `Scheme`, `Host`, `QueryString`] in the `context` on its way through your middleware; something like below, and ensure your middleware runs early-enough in the pipeline:

```
internal class PathRewritingMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public PathRewritingMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        context.Request.Path = "elsewhere/" + context.Request.Path;
        return _next(context);
    }
}
```

---

That said, **don't**, as ASP.NET Core has already [thought of all of this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/url-rewriting?view=aspnetcore-2.2) for you.